# spring jdbctemplate performance issue

Tags: sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I have a dynamic SQL which returns me a list like this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = simpleJdbcTemplate.queryForList( sqlquery);
```

This seems to be running very very slow. I checked if there is any problem with the sql. But found none as it is faster when I run on SQL Developer.

The problem might be when it is processing to convert into List of Maps. I cannot use a `rowmapper` or  a `mapper` because I don't know what columns I will get. Its all dynamic. Do we have any other ways of using `jdbctemplate` other than `queryForList` that returns me `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

I cannot change the return type as UI is completely depend on this structure.

Comment: Could you provide the relevant code?

Comment: Do you want the code for the query that is built? I probably cannot copy and take at one go, as it is built in several methods. At this line,      List<Map<String, Object>> list= this.simpleJdbcTemplate.queryForList( sql);  It just take more time

Comment: Will you please provide more details? How much time it is taking with SQL Developer and how much time it is taking from your code? Also how many rows are getting retrieved?

Comment: In SQL developer it takes around 3 seconds. After the execution of the line(queryForList), it takes around 2 mins. Number of rows are around 34778